# How to construct a array of object by invoking a non-default constructor?

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, constructor

I have a class `hi` with a non-default constructor taking two arguments. I'm trying to construct an array of `hi`s:

```
class hi {
  public:
    hi(int a, int b){};
};

int main() {
  hi *hello;
  int number_of instance = 5;
  hello = new hi[number_of_instance]; // (1)
}
```

How to invoke `hi::hi(int,int)` on the line marked `(1)`?

Comment: `hello = new hi[5]{{1, 2}, {3, 4}, {5, 6}, {7, 8}, {9, 10}};`

Answer (score 6):

> How to invoke `hi::hi(int,int)`?

If `hi` is actually an aggregate type and/or you're using C++11, you can built it simply with:

```
hello = new hi[5]{{1, 2}, {3, 4}, {5, 6}, {7, 8}, {9, 10}};
```

If `hi` is not an aggregate, per se you cannot. But with a bit of improvement, we can achieve it.

1. Declare a private default constructor:

This gives:

```
class hi {
    hi();
public:
    hi(int a, int b){};
};
```

Thhe idea is to provide a default constructor for the standard container to find, even though [`std::is_default_constructible_v<hi>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_default_constructible) is `false`. Obviously, any *actually* attempt to default construct an `hi` will end in a compilation failure.

2. Use an [`std::array`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array) or a [`std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) instead of a C array:

This gives:

```
std::vector<hi> his;
```

3. Use [`std::generate_n`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/generate_n) to construct your objects:

This gives:

```
his.reserve(number_of_instances);
std::generate_n(std::back_inserter(his), number_of_instances, [](){ return hi{0, 0}; });
```

Note though, this vector as a vector of non-default constructibe type is uncomplete, you'll be unable to use all of its features.

[Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/9d368f7eea6b7c38)

Another approach would be to reserve some memory as arrays of `unsigned char` and construct `hi`s instances in it with placement `new`s.

Comment: Can you explain the reason behind the private default constructor? This however does not answer the original question :/

Comment: Reserved memory doesn't count towards the range of the vector. Here `begin(his) == end(his)`

Comment: `std::generate_n(std::back_inserter(his), number_of_instances, [](){ return hi{0, 0}; });`

Comment: @PasserBy This is not the first time I make this mistake. Thx Caleth, taken as is.

Comment: Thanks for the edit. I would use [`std::aligned_storage`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/aligned_storage) instead of `char[]`. It will provide you the same properties, but ensuring all the items are aligned properly (you can get very nasty problems at runtime otherwise).

Comment: @PasserBy this has been turned into a com' wiki. It's all yours to improve.

Comment: why was the call to `generate` incorrect? I'm trying to grasp the difference but I think I'm failing miserably :)

Comment: @Default look at PasserBy's comment ;)

Comment: @Default Jorge comments the last sentence of this answer _"Another approach would be to reserve some memory as arrays of unsigned char and..."_

Answer (score 0):

Use a vector

```
std::vector<hi> hello{{1,2},{1,2},{1,2},{1,2},{1,2}};
```